# not able to to call function inside stored procedure in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

In HANA I have created a function in a schema called A. I am trying the use the function in procedure. While trying to activate the procedure I am getting error message    insufficient privilege: Not authorized. But when I am running in SQL console I am getting the result. Please help to solve this issue

Comment: Are you running SQL statement from console and trying to activate procedure with the same user?

Comment: Yes I am using the same user for running in sql console and to create a stored procedure as well

Comment: SELECT A.DATE_CHECk('20140101')  from dummy; this is the function which I am trying to call inside the procedure. But I am not able to activate it

Comment: I tried in calculation view as well there also I am not able to activate . I am getting same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing a catalog object ( your DATE_CHECK function) with a design time procedure.
In order to activate your design time object, the repository user _SYS_REPO needs to be able to access the referenced objects and grant access to them.

So by

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON a.date_check TO _SYS_REPO with grant option
```

you should be able to fix that and to activate the design time object afterwards.